# android passing items from custom Adapter into intents

Tags: android

hi i am currently using a custom adapter to populate a listView. each item in the listView has a image a title and a background colour. what i'm wanting to achieve is when i click on an item to pass the title and bg colour through to the next activity. 1.) is this possible? and 2.) does anyone know how?

hers my adapter

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MenuItemsSetup>{

    Context context; 
    int layoutResourceId;    
    MenuItemsSetup data[] = null;
    String color[] = null;

    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, MenuItemsSetup[] data, String[] color) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        this.color = color;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ItemHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new ItemHolder();
            holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            String[] backgroundColor = color;


            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ItemHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        MenuItemsSetup menuItem = data[position];
        holder.txtTitle.setText(menuItem.title);
        holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(menuItem.icon);
        row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color[position]));

        return row;
    }

    static class ItemHolder
    {
        ImageView imgIcon;
        TextView txtTitle;

    }
}
```

heres my MenuItemsSetup.java

```
public class MenuItemsSetup {
    public int icon;
    public String color;
    public String title;
    public MenuItemsSetup(){
        super();
    }

    public MenuItemsSetup(int icon, String title) {
        super();
        this.icon = icon;
        this.title = title;

    }
}
```

heres where i am forming the listView in Home.java (ps i'm also using ActionBarSherlock if this is any use)

```
   MenuItemsSetup menuData[] = new MenuItemsSetup[]
                {
                    new MenuItemsSetup(R.drawable.ic_menu_icon1, menuItem1),
                    new MenuItemsSetup(R.drawable.ic_menu_icon2, menuItem2),
                    new MenuItemsSetup(R.drawable.ic_menu_icon3, menuItem3),
                    new MenuItemsSetup(R.drawable.ic_menu_icon4, menuItem4),
                    new MenuItemsSetup(R.drawable.ic_menu_icon5, menuItem5),
                    new MenuItemsSetup(R.drawable.ic_menu_icon6, menuItem6),
                    new MenuItemsSetup(R.drawable.ic_menu_icon7, menuItem7),
                    new MenuItemsSetup(R.drawable.ic_menu_icon8, menuItem8),
                    new MenuItemsSetup(R.drawable.ic_menu_icon9, menuItem9)
                };


       String[] menuBgColours = {menuColor1,menuColor2,menuColor3,menuColor4, menuColor5,.menuColor6
,menuColor7, menuColor8, menuColor9};

                menuListAdapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, menuData, menuBgColours);
                menuGridAdapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_item, menuData, menuBgColours);
                menuList.setAdapter(menuListAdapter);
                menuList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

   private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

          Log.v("Homepage", "menItem clicked = " + menuData[position]);

      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is possible.

You can add onItemClickListener to your ListView and handle the click on the item. The position of the item in the list is passed to this method which you can you find the original item from the list of objects which you use to build you ListView items.

Next, when you create a new Intent to start new activity, you can add whatever values you want to send to the new activity as key-value pairs to this Intent.

In the new activity's onCreate method, you can use

getIntent();

which will return the starting Intent. You will be able to retrieve all the values you passed to this activity using the same keys.

Hope this helps.